# Iterate Array Object inside the itemtpl

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using an array object and put all my records from service call. I can able to put the data inside the arrayobject. But i dont know how to iterate global arrayobject inside the X-template.

```
var Global_array=[];
Global_array.push({
                    "v1":items[i].v1,
                    "v2":items[i].v2,
                    "v3":items[i].v3,
                    "v4":items[i].v4,
                    "v5":items[i].v5,
                });
```

Here i have to iterate and fetch my company details.

```
 '<tr class="mycompanydetail">'
                    +'<tpl '
                                     + '<td>{v1}</td>'
                                    + '<td>{v2}</td>'
                                    + '<td>{v3}</td>'
                                    + '<td>{v4}</td>'

                            +'</tpl></table> '
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 'container' to render your custom tpl you can use 'data' field to send values to your tpl.

For example:

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    tpl: '<tr class="mycompanydetail">'
        + '<tpl for="values">'
        + '<td>{v1}</td>'
        + '<td>{v2}</td>'
        + '<td>{v3}</td>'
        + '<td>{v4}</td>'
        + '</tpl></table> ',
    data: {
        values: Global_array
    }
}
```